# DESCRIBE via database link?

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried to execute the `DESCRIBE` command via a database link, but this was the return message:

```
DESCRIBE <table>@<database>;
ERROR:                               
------------------------------------ 
ERROR: object <table> does not exist 

1 rows selected
```

A `SELECT` on this table works well.

**Does Oracle permitts `DESCRIBE` via a database link?**

I'm using the Oracle SQL Developer 1.5.1.

Edit:

Is there another option to describe a table?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do something with the [all_tab_columns](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2091.htm) table to get some table information.

```
select column_name, data_type from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'TABLE_NAME';
```

Comment: Since it is a SQL*Plus replacement it is not surprising that works. What I don't think works is DESCRIBE through a JDBC connection for example.

Comment: ocdecio: So SQLDeveloper won't get it, because it uses the JDBC?

Comment: It will because it implements the DESCRIBE command. If you write a Java program connecting straight to Oracle with jdbc I doubt it will work. In the end it generates something like select * from v$tables as mentioned by MazarD.

Comment: The only way to prove this is to put a network sniffer and watch what goes back and forth, and then you'll see. Or get the source for yasql.

Comment: The source for yasql shows that it is checking the "all_tab_columns" table.

Comment: Weird thing is....SQLDeveloper won't get the `DESC` but traditional SQLPlus gets it..

Comment: This may work for DB links to Oracle but not to another DBMS like SQL Server, MySQL, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I think DESCRIBE is a SQL*Plus feature. See [here](http://www.ss64.com/ora/desc.html).

Comment: It works with the Oracle SQLDeveloper, too. DESCRIBE works on local tables perfectly.

Comment: It is a tool feature, not a SQL feature so that's why it doesn't work on a regular db connection.

Comment: The other half of the question -- how to get the column information -- using the system views would be a helpful addition to this answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you do a select of the metadata from all_tab_columns for that table present on the DBLink, it'll provide the description of the table.
For Ex:

select * from all_tab_Columns@dblink where table_name='ASDF' and owner='XYZ';

Comment: This may work for DB links to Oracle but not to another DBMS.

Comment: The question was specifically asked considering Oracle in background, so I mentioned in that scenario.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get the description of a table on a remote server would be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TMP_VIEW AS SELECT * FROM TABLE_A@SERVER
/
DESCRIBE TMP_VIEW
/
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using `PL/SQL Developer`.

`DESCRIBE` is not an SQL command, it's a query tool alias that gets converted into a series of queries to the system tables.

`PL/SQL Developer` can not describe tables from remote databases, while native `SQL*Plus` can.

Answer (score 0):

I can't check it right now, but maybe select * from v$tables@remotedb doesn't give similar information?

Answer (score 0):

In PL/SQL Developer, you can right-click on the table name from the tables folder and click on describe...which gives the same result as the describe command in native SQL plus.

Comment: Tables connected by database link do not appear in the Tables branch of the SQL Dev tree (at least up to SQL Dev v.4).

Answer (score 0):

Using Oracle SQL Developer I was able to use DESCRIBE to show the definition of a remote table.  However, I had to use the notation

describe schema.table@database